# how can I show the elements of an array in range? in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to obtain the elements of an array according to a range.

For example: The elements from index 0 to 4 and from 5 to 6.

The idea of ​​this is that I am creating an array with a foreach in jquery and I want to be able to add a CSS style to the elements from 0 to 4 and another style from 5 to 6.

I put my code so they can understand the approach a bit better:

```js
var data = [{
 "dataEarth": [{
  "qty": 7,
  "dataPerson": [{
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }]
 }]
}]


var html = "";
$.each(data, function (index, element){
 $.each(element.dataEarth, function (index,data) {
    console.log(data);
  
    //if the range is 0 to 5 append this
    //html += "<div class='firstClass'><p><strong>Pos. 0 to 5</strong></p></div>";
    //Else if the range is 6 to 7 append this
    //html += "<div class='otherClass'><p><strong>Pos. 6 to 7</strong></p></div>";
   });
});
//$(".json_content").html(html);
```

```html
<div class="json_content"></div>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this:

```js
var data = [{
 "dataEarth": [{
  "qty": 7,
  "dataPerson": [{
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }, {
   "name": "Max",
   "lastName": "CavaniCaracterística",
   "descripcion": "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum doloretitieisorieo"
  }]
 }]
}]

var html = "";

$.each(data[0].dataEarth[0].dataPerson, function (index,el) {        
  
    if (index < 5) {
      html += "<div class='firstClass'><p><strong>Pos. 0 to 5</strong></p></div>";
    } else {
      html += "<div class='otherClass'><p><strong>Pos. 6 to 7</strong></p></div>";
    }
});

$(".json_content").html(html);
```

```html
<div class="json_content"></div>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Alan, I need both elements to be shown, both the div with .firstClass and the div with .otherClass

Comment: They are both showing, just click the botton that says `Full page`